# Python - Continous Button Inputing (Sort of like BCD)

Tags: python, loops, button, tkinter, calculator

I am trying to make something simlar to a calculator, not a full fledge one, but one that could take inputs from buttons and make operations on them. I am trying to figure out how can I get user ınput using buttons. You know how the MS Calculator works, eh? (Or any other calculator basically, or your keyboard itself). It shifts the input you give it and writes it down. So basically ı am asking this: User presses "1" then "5" then "3". I want a variable in my program to be stored as "153".

Sorry for bad explaination, I really have no idea how I can express this problem properly.

I dont really have a code built yet. It just contains the Tk window, buttons, and their functions.

Thanks :) !

Edit: the current code has:
Imports tkinter, creates: (master=Tk())  Creates 10 buttons all labeled 0-9.  And that is pretty much it.

Buttons are labeled as b0, b1, b2 ...

I have tried appending them in to a list, then somehow combining all the elements of the list into one integer. But I couldnt figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would be easier to help you if you post the GUI code you've created, but in general, one way to do this be to store a string representing the current number that is being entered.  Then if the user presses a numerical button, the new digit is appended to the end of the current number.  For example,

For example:

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        # ... this is where you'd set up the rest of the GUI ..
        self.buttons = {}  # Store the calculator buttons in a dictioanry
        for num in [str(x) for x in range(10)]:
            self.buttons[num] = Tkinter.Button(self.keyFrame, text=num, command=self.callbackCreator(num))
        self.currentNumber = ""

    def callbackCreator(self, num):
        return lambda event:self.buttonCallback(num)

    def buttonCallback(key):
        if key in "0123456789":        # Check if the button is a digit or not
            self.currentNumber += key  # add new digit
```

Comment: Looks great! I will see what I can do! By the way, the code really dis nothing but you are right, I will post the code whenever I am at mu computer :)

Comment: Updated the code to fix a problem with the button callback.